# Ionic HTTP for iOS, Android and Browser platform

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm building my app with the **Ionic Framework**.

I'm facing a problem with the *Ionic Native HTTP plugin*, because it works only on iOS and Android platforms.

Is there an alternative to HTTP plugin that works also on Browser platform?

I use it in a straight way:

```
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';

...

constructor(private http: HTTP)

...

this.http.get('http://www.google.com', { 'q' : 'hello' }, {})
.then(data => {
    console.log("OK");
    console.log(data.status);
    console.log(data.data); // data received by server
    console.log(data.headers);    
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log("NO");
    console.log(error.status);
    console.log(error.error); // error message as string
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Ionic 3 with Angular 4.3. 
Maybe you need to use HttpClient of angular than native HTTP. 
you have an example here : https://www.djamware.com/post/59924f9080aca768e4d2b12e/ionic-3-consuming-rest-api-using-new-angular-43-httpclient

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Chrome, you can install this:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

It works for me